# Microsoft Graph API: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

### Problem

When generating an access token for Microsoft Graph API via ADAL, Graph API does not accept the token.

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
  }
}
```

### What the application does

The application should read all users of a tenant. The application is configured to have `User.Read.All` privileges. The application consent is granted by the tenant, where the users should be read from - the application does appear with the privileges in Azure Portal.

### What I have so far

The application worked a few days ago and I changed nothing. Other applications using the same way to authenticate work.

- Recreating to AAD application did not help
- Reinstalling the NuGet packages did not help
- Changing the authority from login.windows.net to login.microsoftonline.com did not help
- Token generation does not work with client secrets and not with a certificate
- Decoding the generated JWT token shows the permissions required for the action

Comment: Which permissions does the JWT show specifically? Because if they are there, it should work if they are the right ones.

Comment: The JWT token shows: "Group.Read.All" and "User.Read.All". I know, that it should work... A ticket at Microsoft is already opened :-)

Comment: The URL you are calling is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` and the `aud` claim in the JWT is `https://graph.microsoft.com` right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas then. Hopefully your ticket gets a response soon :)

Comment: Thank you, we are investigating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

It seems, that the documentation from microsoft is not correct. Listing users requires the `Directory.Read` permission.

#### Update

According to Microsoft it is not clear, if this is a bug in Graph API or the documentation is wrong. 
An issue is open at Github [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/967).

#### Update 2

This issue was fixed in an update of the Graph API in May 2017.

Comment: It seems it is solved now (issue is closed also on GitHub). :)

Comment: Where do I provide `Directory.Read` permissions from Azure portal? I don't see them under IAM section.